# change submit button name based on selected dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the button's name based on the selected values?  This function I found returns `null`.

```js
function myFunction(new_id) {
  if (new_id == 0) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("submit").id = new_id;

  // test new id
  // remove this after testing
  alert(document.getElementById(new_id).id);
}
```

```html
<select id="select" name="select" class="btn btn-block gray dropdown-toggle" required onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
  <option Disabled value="0" selected="selected">- Select Me -</option>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10"> 10</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="">Button</button><br>
```

Comment: Looks like it works at least once.  Which makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the button's value rather than its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be changing the button's ID, you should change its name.

```js
function myFunction(new_id) {
  if (new_id == 0) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("submit").name = new_id;
  alert(document.getElementById("submit").name);
}
```

```html
<select id="select" name="select" class="btn btn-block gray dropdown-toggle" required onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
  <option Disabled value="0" selected="selected">- Select Me -</option>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10"> 10</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="">Button</button><br>
```

However, changing the submit button's name seems like a poor design. I think it would be better to change its value.

Comment: this works for me .. and yeah value is not working with post to another php 
name define only works